# ActionBar Item Click listner is not working

Tags: java, android, navigation

I tried Action Bar like this

[image: Screenshot of my action Bar]

I want like when i click on Actionbar's Item it will print a Toast but it is not working tried a lot.

I Created 2 custom layout,one for Notification custom item and another for Task custom item.

**custom_action_notification_layout.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/noti"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cart_badge"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|end|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="10sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**custom_action_task_layout.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/task"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cart_badge1"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|end|top"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**navigation.menu**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:apps="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/noti"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/custom_action_notification_layout"
    android:title="Refresh"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_task"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/custom_action_task_layout"
    android:title="Task"
    android:icon="@drawable/task"
    app:showAsAction="always" /></menu>
```

Now in my navigationdrawer.class i put thiscode onCreateOptionsMenu(), get ActionView of Notification and Task items and Set OnClick listeners to those ActionView.

**navigation.class**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu);
        // Notification
        final MenuItem itemNotification = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
        MenuItemCompat.setActionView(itemNotification, R.layout.custom_action_notification_layout);
        View actionViewNotification = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(itemNotification);

      //  RelativeLayout notifCount = (RelativeLayout) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(itemNotification);
        actionViewNotification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onOptionsItemSelected(itemNotification);
            }
        });
        final MenuItem itemNotification1 = menu.findItem(R.id.action_task);
        MenuItemCompat.setActionView(itemNotification1, R.layout.custom_action_task_layout);
        View actionViewNotification1 = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(itemNotification1);

    //   RelativeLayout notifCount1 = (RelativeLayout) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(itemNotification1);
        actionViewNotification1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onOptionsItemSelected(itemNotification1);
            }
        });
```

Now finally in onOptionsItemSelected() the code is like

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_refresh: {
            // Do something
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Notification clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.action_task: {
            // Do something
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Task clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Tried in many ways but not working at all please help out from this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Create two `custom layout`, one for `Notification` custom `item` and another for `Task` custom `item`.

**custom_action_notification_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_notification"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cart_badge"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|end|top"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="10sp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**custom_action_task_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_task"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cart_badge"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|end|top"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="10sp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**2.** Create a `menu` XML containing `Notification` and `Task` item. Use attribute `app:actionLayout` to set `custom layout` to each `item`.

**custom_menu.xml**

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_notification"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_notification"
        android:title="Notification"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_action_notification_layout"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_task"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_task"
        android:title="Task"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_action_task_layout"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

**3.** In your Activity `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, get `ActionView` of `Notification` and `Task` items and Set `OnClick` listeners to those `ActionView`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_menu, menu);

    // Notification
    final MenuItem itemNotification = menu.findItem(R.id.action_notification);
    View actionViewNotification = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(itemNotification);
    actionViewNotification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onOptionsItemSelected(itemNotification);
        }
    });

    // Task
    final MenuItem itemTask = menu.findItem(R.id.action_task);
    View actionViewTask = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(itemTask);
    actionViewTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onOptionsItemSelected(itemTask);
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

**4.** Finally, In `onOptionsItemSelected()` do the rest:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_notification: {
            // Do something
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Notification clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.action_task: {
            // Do something
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Task clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**FYI,** I have checked `Notification` and `Task` menu item `click` event by showing `Toast` messages.

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

**In your updated code use:**

```
MenuItemCompat.setActionView(itemNotification, R.layout.custom_action_notification_layout);
View actionViewNotification = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(itemNotification);
```

**Instead of**

```
View actionViewNotification = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(itemNotification);
MenuItemCompat.setActionView(itemNotification, R.layout.custom_action_notification_layout);
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);  menuItem for what?

Comment: can you please provide code of your navigation menu and custom layout for badgemenu and badgetask?

Comment: I have updated my answer with full implementation of custom menu item with click actions. Hope this will help you find out your issue.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: This is an working example. Follow all the four steps.

Comment: i used Relative layout instead framelayout and it is working but toast is not generating

Comment: View actionViewTask = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(itemTask); giving null object refrence

Comment: so that i am using         RelativeLayout notifCount1 = (RelativeLayout) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(itemNotification1);
 but none are working should i paste my full code?

Comment: You should set ActionView first. Update you code as below: MenuItemCompat.setActionView(itemNotification, R.layout.custom_action_notification_layout);
        View actionViewNotification = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(itemNotification);

Comment: Or you can set action view from `menu.xml`. as i mentioned in my answer section 2. Use app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_action_notification_layout"

Comment: i did exactly the same as you said but not working only one diffrence is that i used relative layout instead frame layout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142257/discussion-between-weal-infotech-and-ferdous-ahamed).

Comment: My pleasure :)... really happy to know that its working

Comment: Sure, your question also seems useful for others. Done

Comment: Manually calling `onOptionsItemSelected()` is dodgy, since it calls `super.onOptionsItemSelected()` and can cause class to misbehave